# Output QProcess does not work after creating exe with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, exe, qprocess

I created a GUI with PyQt which calls another Python script with QProcess. The output should be written to the GUI. When I run the program as a Python script it works fine. However when I create a exe with PyInstaller nothing is written to the gui. So, it seems like the process is not starting. What I am doing wrong?

Here the command I use to create the exe:

```
python -m PyInstaller PreGui_pipeline.py --onefile --add-data "PostGui_pipeline_test.py;."
```

Below the part where I start QProcess:

```
self.message("START OF THE FLASHING PROCESS \n")
self.p = QProcess()
self.p.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.handle_stdout)
self.p.finished.connect(self.finish_flash)

        
try:
    # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
    base_path = sys._MEIPASS
except Exception:
    base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

path = os.path.join(base_path, "PostGui_pipeline_test.py")

self.p.start("python", [path, str(self.flash), str(self.full_auto), self.config_path])
```

And here the code of the script which is called by QProcess (no a little cutted for easier understanding):

```
def cprint(*args):

    for output_text in args:
        old_stdout.write(">>" + str(output_text) + "<<")
    old_stdout.flush()
    os.fsync(old_stdout.fileno())

if __name__ == "__main__":

    old_stdout = sys.stdout 
    cprint("Test")
```

So when I run the py file it writes "Test" to the GUI and when I run it as a exe nothing happens.

Comment: It's probably a path issue. See if this answers your question: [Best way to call subprocess scripts in a Python exe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56564441)

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for your answer! I tried that right now and it still doesn´t work :( any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry but "doesn't work" isn't a sufficient answer. What did you try? How? Also, are you sure that the file is actually included and that the path you're using in the exe is correct? And that the `python` command is properly run, using QProcess properties and signals?

Comment: @musicamante I tried to implement the answer of the question you shared and again everything works fine when I run the python script but a soon as the exe is created the QProcess starts but doesn´t call the other python script. The file is fir sure included and I can´t say if the path to the exe is correct.

Comment: please include an [example]